# how to used await function in express javascript

Tags: javascript

I am running this code but it give me
this error.
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top-level bodies of modules

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => { //register/signup
    try{
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        users.push({
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            name: req.body.name,
            email:req.body,email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })
        res,redirect('/login')
    }catch{
        res.redirect('/register')
    }
    console.log(users)
})`enter code here`
```

Comment: res,redirect('/login') shuld be  res.redirect('/login') type error probably

Comment: `await is only valid in async functions`. Make your callback async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just mark the callback function passed to the `app.post` method as `async`.

```js
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => { 
    try{
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        users.push({
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            name: req.body.name,
            email:req.body,email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })
        res,redirect('/login')
    }catch{
        res.redirect('/register')
    }
    console.log(users)
})
```